# iTextSharp automatically shrinking images when end of the page reach

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp to display images in a pdf report. Here I want display two images in a row and it's working as expected but having a issue when end of the page reaches. The issue is that last row images get shrink to fit in same page, it doesn't automatically add it to the next page. All images having same dimension and resolution.

[image: Click here for screenshot]

Comment: You should probably provide some code to reproduce your issue. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide us with the code.

I wrote the test below (although it's in java, there should be no problem) and the results seem to be correct.

```
    public void tableWithImagesTest01() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String testName = "tableWithImagesTest01.pdf";
    String outFileName = destinationFolder + testName;
    String cmpFileName = sourceFolder + "cmp_" + testName;

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A3);

    Image image1 = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(sourceFolder + "itis.jpg"));
    Table table = new Table(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(image1));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(image1));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Hello")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("World")));
    }
    doc.add(table);

    doc.close();
    Assert.assertNull(new CompareTool().compareByContent(outFileName, cmpFileName, destinationFolder, "diff"));
}
```

The result pdf looks like this:
[image]

Maybe you use summat `image1.setAutoScale(true);`? Still we need your code to look at.

Comment: thanks, finally i got solution for this problem. image.ScaleToFitHeight = false;

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (considering all images have the same dimension and resolution) would be to manually insert a new page and pagebreak every time you have inserted the maximum number of images to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a comment below, the solution that works is, on the individual images you need to set:

image.ScaleToFitHeight = false;

Likely to happen when keeping rows together